# alternative to nested try catch in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, try-catch

I am working on MEAN STACK web application and in nodejs I want to use async await with try catch block. In following example I want to make code in straight instead of using nested multiple try and catch. Here I need to pass different type of custom errors to front-end if any error arise.

> EX :

```
public async create(req: Request, res: Response) {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    try {
        ...
        ...
        ...

        let userResult = await userModel.addBasickInfo(userData);

        ...
        ...
        ...

        try {
            ...
            ...
            ...

            let userAddressResult = await userProfileModel.addAddress(addressData);
            ...
            ...
            ...

            try {
                ...
                ...
                ...

                let userProfileResult = await userAddressModel.addProfile(profileData);
                ...
                ...
                ...

                return (<any>res).sendResponse(data, 'Information saved successfully');

            } catch (err) {
                return (<any>res).sendError(err.error ? err : new ErrorException('BadRequestError', "Error while adding user profile information"));
            }

        } catch (err) {
            return (<any>res).sendError(new ErrorException('BadRequestError', 'Error while adding user address'));
        }

    } catch (err) {
        return (<any>res).sendError(err.error ? err : new ErrorException('BadRequestError', 'Error while adding user information'));
    }
    
}
```

Please help me to improve this code.

Comment: Why is nesting needed? Why not `try { // addBasickInfo } catch {}; try { // addAddress } catch {}`

Comment: Is it necessary to do this one after the other? Since your first call result is not being used in the second call, you could use them independently in parallel as well.

Comment: @Harshal : Yes, it necessary to do this one after the other because user id is stored in userAddressModel and userProfileModel. and user address id stored in user profile model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this pattern instead of nesting the try-catch block.

```
public async create(req: Request, res: Response) {

    try {
        let userResult = await userModel.addBasickInfo(userData);

    } catch (err) {
        return (<any>res).sendError(err.error ? err : new ErrorException('BadRequestError', 'Error while adding user information'));
    }

    try {
        let userAddressResult = await userProfileModel.addAddress(addressData);

    } catch (err) {
        return (<any>res).sendError(new ErrorException('BadRequestError', 'Error while adding user address'));
    }
    try {

        let userProfileResult = await userAddressModel.addProfile(profileData);
        return (<any>res).sendResponse(data, 'Information saved successfully');

    } catch (err) {
        return (<any>res).sendError(err.error ? err : new ErrorException('BadRequestError', "Error while adding user profile information"));
    }
}
```